# Overloading memory mapped file loader (C++)

Tags: c++, linux

Is it possible to overload memory mapped file loader? In case of page fault, Linux kernel would not load the requested data from disk, but instead of it, user-defined function would be called, which would fill the memory page.

I would like to use this for memory mapping of huge compressed raster file. Used compression algorithm allows fast block decompression. User-defined loading function would decompress the file page by page on the fly.

The compressed files are read-only. User-space solution is preferred.

Comment: Sounds like you need to be writing a FUSE driver.

Comment: Or a server for any of a variety of network filesystems with mount support

Comment: In C++, you can overload a function. Overloading is creating several different functions that share the same name but have different types. Is memory mapped file loader a function? Does it have a name or type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to overload memory mapped file loader? In case of page fault, Linux kernel would not load the requested data from disk, but instead of it, user-defined function would be called, which would fill the memory page.

It is possible and some libraries do just that. See [libsigsegv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libsigsegv/).

Install a signal handler for `SIGSEGV` with `sigaction` using the following signature for your handler:

```
void sigsegv_handler(int, siginfo_t* si, void*) {
    si->si_addr; // Memory location which caused the page fault.
    // mmap the missing page and return here

    // On error alternatives:
    //   * restore the previous SIGSEGV handler and return (the default one dumps core), or
    //   * abort() (dumps core), or
    //   * _exit(EXIT_FAILURE).
}
```

Comment: I believe you also have to set a bit to tell it to re-run the offending instruction.

Comment: @wallyk What bit would that be?

Comment: It looks like the semantics have changed since I last looked into signal handling (like in 1995).  The instruction restarts after handler exit if `sigaction()` is called with the flag SA_RESTART.  Otherwise, presumably the instruction is skipped.

Comment: @wallyk I was under impression that `SA_RESTART` only makes some system calls restart automatically instead of failing with `EINTR`. The normal behaviour of OS is to continue when the signal handler returns. Hence, one can get into infinite loop if `SIGSEGV` signal handler returns without mapping the faulting page.

Comment: How would the operating system "skip" an instruction on architectures like e.g. x86 where instructions can be anywhere from a single byte to a dozen bytes long? It would need to employ something like a disassembler to do that.

Comment: @Damon:  Strategies vary based on CPU model, but many interrupt handlers basically "disassemble the instruction" by using tables of instruction data (sorry, can't find that anywhere now; I last saw it years ago).  More advanced CPU models have a "single step" flag in the PSR which causes an interrupt after the instruction completes.

Comment: @wallyk The OS restarts the instruction upon return from `SIGSEGV` handler. Like from any other signal handler. If you dispute that, please post your references.