# Invalidating memory page

Tags: c++, linux

I am implementing a reader of huge compressed raster files. Decompression is performed partially on the fly. Only requested regions of the raster are decompressed and stored in memory cache. Reader works similarly as memory mapping of a file but the data is not mapped to memory 1:1, it is decompressed.

It is implemented using anonymous memory mapping:

```
char* raster_cache = static_cast<char*>(mmap(0, UNCOMPRESSED_RASTER_SIZE, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0));
```

Reading of an area which is not cached yet emits segmentation violation signal which is caught and handled using libsigsegv (see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621427/overloading-memory-mapped-file-loader-c)):

```
struct CacheHandlerData
{
    std::mutex mutex;

    // other data needed for decompression
};

int cache_sigsegv_handler(void* fault_address, void* user_data)
{
    void* page_address = reinterpret_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(fault_address) & ~(PAGE_SIZE - 1));

    CacheHandlerData* data = static_cast<CacheHandlerData*>(user_data);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(data->mutex);

    unsigned char cached = 0;
    mincore(page_address, 1, &cached);
    if (!cached)
    {
        mprotect(page_address, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_WRITE);

        // decompress whole page

        mprotect(page_address, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The problem is that cached pages stay in memory forever. Because i write to the pages, they are marked as dirty and never invalidated.

QUESTION: Is there some possibility to mark pages as not dirty?

In case the system is running out of memory, the pages would be removed from memory similarly to a normal disk cache. It would also be needed to call mprotect(page_address, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_NONE) for the removed pages in order to cause a segmentation violation when the page is accessed again.

Thank you.

EDIT: I could use temporary file backed mapping instead of anonymous one. Pages would be swapped to disk in case the system is out of memory. But this solution loses benefits from using compressed data (smaller disk size, probably faster reading).

Comment: You can try fuse, I suppose it has mmap hooks.

Comment: By the way there is list of "safe to call" from signal handler functions, see signal(7). And I suppose many of functions in your signal handler unsafe to call.